# What's wrong with below ruby coerce method?

Tags: ruby

Below is the code.

```
class Fixnum
  def coerce o
    p o
    p self
    [o.to_a, self]
  end
end

p ((1..10) << 14)
```

What I want is when I call `<<` on a Range object, I'll convert the Range to an Array and append the object to it. The code does not work as I expected and I need some advice.

---

*Update:*

Thanks guys for the comments. Actually I'm not doing monkey-patch for some particular intentions and I just want to lean the mechanism behind the `coerce` method. I've done something below.

```
[26] pry(main)> 1 + "3"
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
from (pry):24:in `+'
[27] pry(main)> class String
[27] pry(main)*   def coerce o
[27] pry(main)*     [o, self.to_i]
[27] pry(main)*   end
[27] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[28] pry(main)> 1 + "3"
=> 4
[29] pry(main)>
```

From my understand I'm doing almost the same thing with my first example and it works. I still can't see the difference between those two examples and I need a pair of eagle eyes.

---

*Update 2*

To make my problem clear I've refactored my first example to:

```
C:\>pry
[1] pry(main)> (1..10) << 14
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for 1..10:Range
from (pry):1:in `__pry__'
[2] pry(main)> class Fixnum
[2] pry(main)*   def coerce o
[2] pry(main)*     [o.to_a, self]
[2] pry(main)*   end
[2] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> (1..10) << 14
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for 1..10:Range
from (pry):7:in `__pry__'
[4] pry(main)> [1, 2, 3] << 4
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[5] pry(main)>
```

Comment: A range is not an array. What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: You don't call `coerce` anywhere, and it shouldn't be part of Fixnum, it should be part of Range, which is what you're manipulating. But, beyond that'd I'd question whether you should even monkey-patch a class, since it's such a trivial operation to do in-line: `(1..10).to_a << 14` or `[*(1..10)] << 14`.

Comment: Oh I think I may found the result of my problem. For the example `1 + "3"`, `1` has a method called `+` and it failed just because the parameter `"3"` is not the correct type. For the Range `(1..10)`, it just doesn't have a method called `<<`. That's the difference I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is to add the `<<` method to the Range class.

```
class Range
  def <<(o)
    self.to_a << o
  end
end
```

Since you want to put `<<` after an instance of a Range, you need to add such a method to the Range class. This will then return an array with the passed in item appended.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I'd have written. Now explain *why* it is the right thing to do.